# Boost.Python not the .lib

Tags: c++, boost, boost-python

I think I have built it properly. I have other boost libraries working. I am getting the following error

> Error: *SNK1104    cannot open file 'boost_pythonPY_MAJOR_VERSIONPY_MINOR_VERSION-vc141-mt-x32-1_67.lib'.*

I'm on windows using Visual Studios, with boost 1.67

Comment: Actually, I've seen where its being  built. It's an auto linking issue as far as I can tell.

I can find two boost_python* .lib and two .dlls. It's just not linking to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`boost-python` is notoriously hard to install. Make sure you specify `with-python` when building from source. Something like this:

Download and configure boost

```
cd boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine
build.bat mingw
```

Add this to your path

```
C:\boost_1_55_0\tools\build\v2\engine\bin.ntx86
```

Build from source

```
bjam toolset=gcc --with-python link=shared
```

Add this to your path

```
C:\boost_1_55_0\stage\lib
```

Comment: I'm using boost 1.67, I don't have a v2 folder in build? Also it being hard to install really does make me feel better.

Comment: The most important step is `bjam toolset=gcc --with-python link=shared`. The boost website has a better set of instructions: https://theboostcpplibraries.com/introduction-installation